# Iterate through every discord channel and find if a certain channel exists discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I wanted to create a ticket system so i created a cog and started iterating
through every channel to see if the channel's name matches the user's ticket channel name so there
wouldn't be any duplicates.

```
        for guild in client.guilds:
            for c in guild.channels:
                if str(c) == f"{username}-ticket":
                    room_exists = True
                    break
                else:
                    room_exists = False
        if room_exists:
            print(room_exists)
            return await ctx.send('You already have an open ticket!')
        if not room_exists:
            return await channel.send(f'{user_tag} Created this ticket, reason: {reason}')
```

For some reason i can't figure out the bot creates a room and sends a 'You already have an open ticket!' message even though room_exists == True

Answer (score 1):

Iterating through every channel is not an optimized solution. You should use [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get).

If `discord.utils.get` can't find the channel, it returns `None`. Here what you can do:

```py
ticket_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.text_channels, name=f'{username}-ticket')
if ticket_channel:
    print(ticket_channel)
    await ctx.send('You already have an open ticket!')
    return
else:
    await channel.send(f'{user_tag} Created this ticket, reason: {reason}')
    return
```